# Can we run existing program with hadoop or we need to modify it in mapreduce style only?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote below python program to process data from excel file. But now is it possible to run same program with hadoop mapreduce, how the conventional program and mapreduce program differs?

```
import xlrd

with xlrd.open_workbook('interference.xlsx') as book:
# 0 corresponds for 1st worksheet, usually named 'Book1'
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# gets col C values
B = [ B for B in sheet.col_values(1) ]


# gets col D values
D = [ D for D in sheet.col_values(3) ]


# combines D and E elements to tuples, combines tuples to list
# ex. [ ('Incoming', 18), ('Outgoing', 99), ... ]
data = list( zip(B,D) )

# gets total no of get request attempts for each UID

x=1
for uid in data:
    while x <=44 :
        attempts = sum( tup[1] for tup in data if tup[0] == x )
        print("Total attempts for UID",x, attempts)
        x=x+1
```

Comment: Are you planning to use python or java in the mapreduce implementation.

Comment: I want to use python @Amit

Answer (score 0):

it's not possibile to run the same program as a MapReduce job with Hadoop.

MapReduce is a programming paradigm based on the idea to divide computation in two phases: the first (mapping) divides the problem into many subproblems and resolve each of them; the second phase (reducing) puts together all the results of the subproblems to obtain the final solution.

I suggest you to take a look at the WordCount program, which is the Hadoop equivalent of Hello World: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount

Comment: Thanks @ Andrea !! it was really helpful .